# How can i insert a fragment in Intent (Android)

Tags: java, android

Thats My Code. I have read something about an fragmentmanager but i dont know how to implement that.:/

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,Fragment.class );
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        },splashTimeOut);
```

Comment: Intent is  used for passing information between  different android components, and  the type of information is limited to only a few data types like String, Integer, Boolean etc . So you cannot pass a fragment into it and possibly thinking in the wrong direction. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

this the way to impelement it in kotlin

```
lateinit var homeFragment: HomeFragment

  homeFragment= HomeFragment()
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.grid,homeFragment)//replacing a view in here i use linear layout
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            .commit()
```

I wish this can help

Answer (score 0):

startActivity() can not be used for non-activity class.
You can add that Fragment into any activity and then try to start with above code, replace Activity in place of Fragment.class